Transitivity synchronization order
In JLS 17.4.7.2 says:

The happens-before order is given by the transitive closure of synchronizes-with edges and program order. It must be a valid partial order: reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric.

The other orders have no such description. I'm interested in how to reason about SO without this property.
Let's take a simple program:
volatile int v = 3; 




T1
T2




int r1 = v;
int r2 = v;



Two orders of magnitude can be constructed for it
w(v) -SO-> r1 -SO-> r2

or
      w(v)
      /  \
    SO    SO
   /       \
  \/       \/
  r1        r2

If SO were transitive, they would be indentical, but they are not.
Now let's try to translate to HBO.
1.
w(v) -SW-> r1 -NO_SW-> r2
w(v) -HB-> r1
but no HB to r2




      w(v)
      /  \
    HB    HB
   /       \
  \/       \/
  r1        r2

It is not clear to me which of these two considerations is correct. Is there a read-read HB? Also, is it possible to do common-cause relationships like in example 2?

Looks like I was wrong, SO is a partial order, so it has the same properties.

You bolded the word, "transitive." But how does "transitive" pertain to anything in your question? if '↣' is a transitive operator, and if A↣B, and B↣C, then you can conclude that A↣C. But, your example does not have that same structure. If 'A' is the initialization of the variable, and 'B' and 'C' are the two reads, then what you have is A↣B and A↣C. "Transitivity" does not allow you to infer any relationship between B and C from those facts.

@SolomonSlow, my first assumption is wrong?
if SO transitive and  w(v) -SO-> r1 -SO-> r2 then w(v) -SO-> r2
I was under the impression that SO allowed read-read. Although after reading more about partial order, I realize that both options are legitimate.

You wrote; w(v)-SO->r1-SO->r2. Did you intend that to mean the same as w(v)->SO->r1 and r1-SO->r2? That's what it looks like. But if so, why did you choose r1-SO->r2? Why did you not choose r2-SO->r1? What do you see in your example that suggests any particular ordering between the read operation in the T1 thread and the read operation in the T2 thread?

It doesn't matter to me which reading comes first. Both of these executions options are possible.
By the way, and which actions have no SO either directly or indirectly. For example, in one thread write_volatile(v, 42) and in the second while(v!=42). Theoretically, it's possible that we'll just never see v from this point of view. What would guarantee us any progress at all...
Formally:
r(v) -SO-> r(v) -SO-> r(v) -SO-> r(v) -SO-> ..., but no w(v, 42) -SO-> r(v).

I guess I have no idea what you meant when you wrote -SO->. The way you were throwing around words like, "reflexive," "transitive," and "antisymmetric," I thought you were talking about a mathematical relationship. But, then you replied to my question with, "It doesn't matter to me which reading comes first." We apparently are talking past each other. I don't think I'll be able to understand what you really are asking.

There are two possible executions that will produce the same result. I have chosen one particular one.
Specifically:
"Every execution has a synchronization order. A synchronization order is a total order over all of the synchronization actions of an execution."
Is it possible that SO has irreflexivity, asymmetry, transitivity properties. Otherwise it will not order all the actions.
Transitivity was important to me as I could not build a sw bridge, for hb.

For example here they write about it exactly: "In a (strict) total order each event is ordered with respect to every other event, resulting in a linear (sequential) chain of events."
Does this apply to SO?

Happens-before ordering is usually partial -- which means, not total -- and two events may not be ordered relative to each other.

@LouisWasserman, I agree. Does this also apply to SO?
